# Gnu fortran compiler write option

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, compilation, fortran, gfortran

I use **FORTRAN gnu compiler** to compile a piece of code written using **fortran(.f90)**. Unlike in other compilers the output of write statement are not displayed in the screen rather written in the output file.

For example I have placed "`write(*,*)` 'Check it here'" in the middle of the source code so that this message is displayed in the screen when someone runs the compiled version of the code.

I dont understand why this message is not displayed in the terminal window while running the code, but it is written in the output file.

I would appreciate your help to resolve this !!

>

I am compiling these source codes:

https://github.com/firemodels/fds/tree/master/Source

makefile that I am using to compile the code is located here:

https://github.com/firemodels/fds/tree/master/Build/mpi_intel_linux_64

I run the program using a executable that makefile creates

The version of the compiler that I am using is

GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609

>

Thank you.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is not expected. The gfortran compiler is not the issue. Please post the code.

Comment: Please show us exactly what you are doing. We need the *exact* code(see [mcve]) and the *exact* way how you are compiling it (all compiler options and flags you are using) and how you are running it. We need your operating system and the compiler version.

Comment: Please put the code **here into this question**. A code at an external link is not enough and your code is **way too big**. See [ask] and [mcve]. You must tell us where exactly that error happens. The official reason to close a question is: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess you opened a file as unit 6.  Do not use units less than 10 for your own files.

Comment: Perhaps also the code is being run within a script which automatically pipes. Please post the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way bigger picture: Is there a reason you're building FDS from source rather than downloading binaries directly from NIST i.e. from https://pages.nist.gov/fds-smv/downloads.html ?

Granted, if you're qualifying the code for safety-related use, you may need to compile from source rather than use someone else's binaries. You may need to add specific info to a header page such as code version, date of run, etc. to satisfy QA requirements.

If you're just learning about FDS (practicing fire analysis, learning about CFD, evaluating the code), I'd strongly suggest using NIST's binaries. If you need/want to compile it from source, we'll need more info to diagnose the problem.

That said, operating on the assumption that you have a use case that requires that you build the code, your specific problem seems to be that writing to the default output unit `*` isn't putting the output where you expect.

Modern Fortran provides the `iso_fortran_env` module which formalizes a lot of the obscure trivia of Fortran, in this case, default input and output units.

In the module you're editing, look for something like:

```
use iso_fortran_env
```

or

```
use iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit
```

or

```
use, intrinsic:: iso_fortran_env, only: STDOUT => output_unit
```

If you see an import of `output_unit` or (as in the last case) an alias to it, write to that unit instead of to `*`.

If you don't an import from `iso_fortran_env`, add the last line above to the routine or module you're printing from and write to `STDOUT` instead of `*`.

That may or may not fix things, depending on if the FDS authors do something strange to redirect IO. They might; I'm not sure how writing to screen works in an MPI environment where the code may run in parallel on a number of networked machines (I'd write to a networked logging system in that case, but that's just me). But in a simple case of a single instance of the code running, writing to `output_unit` is more precise than writing to `*` and more portable and legible than writing to `6`.

Good luck with FDS; I tried using it briefly to model layer formation from a plume of hydrogen gas in air. FDS brought my poor 8 CPU machine to its knees so I went back to estimating it by hand instead of trying to make CFD work...

Comment: So you are suggesting, one should generally use `write(STDOUT,` instead of `write(*,`? I hope not. He/she must have done something wrong ifit does something that strange.

Comment: There is nothing imprecise about writing to `*`. It is perfectly fine. How would you suggest to fix the `print` statements if they (and it is likely) exhibit the same problem?

Comment: To me, `write(*,...)` is ambiguous in that the Fortran processor to decide what `*` means; it's likely standardized and documented, but it still makes me uneasy. I much prefer `output_unit` because I never have to guess what my code is doing. I would much rather explicitly specify the unit. because it's one less element left to chance. I also avoid `print`, but that's another story. If `write(*,` works for you, great; it makes me nervous so I avoid it. :)

Comment: `output_unit` is _defined_ as the thing where `write(output_unit...)` and `write(*...)` have the same effect. There's nothing ambiguous at all.  For `output_unit` from the intrinsic module, that is.  I'd be much more nervous that someone has instead used a different variable with a wholly inappropriate value.

Comment: And that's why I suggested using `use, intrinsic:: iso_fortran_env`, specifically so `output_unit` is taken from the canonical source. I agree that `*` is not ambiguous with a copy of the language spec in front of you. I don't have that much desk(top) space so I find explicitly specifying the unit clearer and cleaner. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to compile it from Source code because, for my project I need to modify the codes in order to have additional numerical schemes.

I searched in the source codes, `grep -r 'iso_fortran_env'` but got nothing in return.

Also I tried using `write(1 upto 10, *)`, it was still written in the `.out` file

I got one more clue from my several trial, FDS has all together 34 `.f90` source files and the write statement, `write(*,*)` written in one of the file `read.f90` is displayed in the screen while same syntax in other file would write an output to `.out` file.